# Склонение двойных и более имен иностранцев в русском языке

Tags: склонение-фамилий

У меня вопрос по правилам склонения иностранных имен и фамилий, когда у иностранца два и более имени. Для примера возьмем французское имя - Давид Жан Жак Мерель. Здесь 3 имени (где Давид - основное) и одна фамилия (Мерель). Согласно правилам русского языка иноязычные имена и фамилии, оканчивающиеся на гласный звук, исключая безударные -а и -я не склоняются. Например КианУ РивЗ, но КианУ РивзУ (очень удачно его Ф.И. демонстрирует правило, простите). Ни одно из имен и фамилия Давида под правило не подходит (все заканчиваются на согласные). Таким образом, очевидно, что в родительном падеже Ф.И. склоняется - Давида Мереля. Но как быть с полным написанием? Нужно ли склонять все 4 слова, то есть писать Давида Жана Жака Мереля, или следует использовать правило русского языка для двойных фамилий (как Мамин-Сибиряк), когда первая часть не склоняется, хотя это (Жан Жак) и имена? То есть Давида Жан Жак Мереля.
Это может быть очень важно для официальных документов.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: С чего бы это в фамилии "Мамин-Сибиряк" склоняться только второй части? Правило гласит: "В русских двойных фамилиях первая часть склоняется, если она сама по себе употребляется как фамилия". Фамилия "Мамин" вполне себе существует, поэтому "Мамина-Сибиряка", "Маминым-Сибиряком" и т. п.

Answer (score 2):

Косвенно этот вопрос обговаривается в «Справочнике издателя и автора» Мильчина.

> 3.2.10. Нерусские двойные, тройные и т. д. имена
>
> Такие европейские, американские, австралийские имена пишутся с прописной буквы каждое, независимо от раздельного или дефисного их написания. Напр.: *Джордж Ноэл Гордон Байрон, Джон Десмонд Бернал, Пьер Огюстен Бомарше, Чарлз Роберт Дарвин, Генри Уодсуорт Лонгфелло, Джон Стюарт Милль, Антуан Франсуа Прево, Катарина Сусанна Причард, Пьер Жозеф Прудон, Франклин Делано Рузвельт, Жан Жак Руссо, Жан Поль Сартр, Роберт Льюис Стивенсон, Перси Биш Шелли, Чарлз Спенсер Чаплин, Георг Вильгельм Фридрих Гегель, Эрнст Теодор Амадей Гофман, Фридрих Вильгельм Йозеф Шеллинг, Торберн Улаф Бергман, Пьер Паоло Пазолини, Никколо Уго Фосколо, Педро Ортега Диас, Хосе Рауль Капабланка, Давид Альфаро Сикейрос, Ханс Кристиан Андерсен, Питер Пауэл Рубенс, Бронислав Войцех Линке, Михал Клеофас Огиньский, Карел Яромир Эрбен, Квинт Гораций Флакк, Марк Фабий Квинтилиан, Гай Юлий Цезарь, Марк Туллий Цицерон, Мария-Антуанетта*.
>
> **Примечание.** В отношении раздельного или дефисного написания иноязычных имен нет единообразия. В лингвистических статьях приводятся аргументы в пользу дефисного написания всех многокомпонентных имен. Печать либо ориентируется на раздельное написание всех имен, принятое в энциклопедиях (напр., в БСЭ, «Большом энциклопедическом словаре»), либо допускает дефисное написание нек. французских имен, как правило, закрепленное традицией (в них первое имя в косвенных падежах обычно остается без изменений, напр.: *Жан-Жак Руссо — Жан-Жаку Руссо, Пьер-Анри Симон — Пьер-Анри Симону*), в соответствии с рекомендацией справочных изданий по русскому языку (напр.: Розенталь Д. Э., Джанджакова Е. В., Кабанова Н. П. Справочник по русскому языку: Правописание, произношение, литературное редактирование. М., 2005, III, § 13.3). Рекомендуется принять одно из применяемых в печати решений и последовательно придерживаться его во всех изданиях.

Если порыться по правилам и справочникам, то пишут, что, как правило, склоняются первые части двойных, тройных и более имен, написанных раздельно, и не склоняются первые части таких имен, пишущихся через дефис.

Надеюсь, найдутся люди, которые смогут дополнить эту информацию.